# PowerShell how to get a reference to a function or cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I would like to get a reference to a function or cmdlet.

For instance, I would like to reference the Get-ChildItem cmdlet.
I don't want to call it, I want a reference to the function, that I could then pass to another function.

Is there a syntax to do this?

I am aware that I can Invoke-Expression with a string 'Get-ChildItem'.  Is this the only way to handle this situation?

Comment: Do you need to reference it for information on the cmdlet (like the Cmdlet name), or are you just trying to store it to call it later, like a script block? Can you provide any pseudo code showing the use case?

Comment: I'd like to store it to call it later, like a script block.  I just didn't want to have to wrap the function in a script block

Comment: If I could convert the function into a script block that would be fine also

Comment: What would be the advantage of doing this? If you plan on calling it later (with or without parameters) you'll need to type it out at some point, right? You could use ```Get-Command``` if you need to just capture it, and then call it later with ```Invoke-Expression $MyCommand.Name```, but that seems like more work. I'm only asking to try and better understand what you're trying to do so that I can look at it in the proper light.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```powershell
$gci = Get-Command Get-ChildItem
```

This will do it.. but since you haven't said how you want to use it I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Edit: after seeing your comment, it seems you want to store it in a variable. You could do that with script functions, but I don't think you could do that with a cmdlet's contents like that, unless you wrap it in a scriptblock first.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks!  I couldn't figure out how to type Get-ChildItem without it evaluating (i.e. calling the cmdlet)

Comment: If it's a script function, you could also check out `Get-Item Function:\My-FunctionName` (use `Get-ChildItem Function:` to see them all).

Comment: If it's a script function, there is even a simpler way: `$function:FunctionName`

Answer (score 1):

Invoke-Expression is the tool made to handle just this use case.  Note that if you need to define some variables within a string when it is executed, you should escape the variable with a grave mark ` or you can instead define the here-string with a single quote instead.

```
$commands = @"
`$computername = `$env:computername
get-wmiobject win32_computersystem -computername `$computername
"@

Invoke-Expression $commands
>Domain              : FOXDEPLOY
Manufacturer        : Dell Inc.
Model               : Latitude E6540
Name                : DELLBOOK
PrimaryOwnerName    : Windows User
TotalPhysicalMemory : 17080483840
```

Comment: Thanks Fox, I am making some generic functions, and I didn't want to have to resort to building strings to evaluate the passed in functions.  I'd like to be able to pass a function reference (i.e. the result of Get-Command) and splat an Arguments hash to the function to call it, rather than building the strings myself.

Comment: Josh, could you show me an example of what you'd like to do.  Use pseudo code if needed.  I'm not sure I understand what you're asking to do.

Comment: I tried writing a few example, but it seems like in each a scriptblock is the better solution.  I guess it was more of an academic question?

Comment: If you're asking how to store the output of a command for later use, you can do that with $output = get-ADComputer, for instance.  Sorry if I totally missed the point of your question!